# Continuous for loop doesn't terminate C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

I've been trying too find the problem with this for ages, i cant seem too get my head around it.
When a number above value 2 is entered, the program just continously outputs ' ' or '*' and doesn't terminate, and give the correct output.

Can anyone see what im doing wrong? here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

     int xx; 

cout << "Enter the Height (odd positive numbers only): " << endl; 
cin >> xx; 

for(float y; y < xx; y++)
{
    for(float x; x < xx; x++)
    {
        x = abs( x - ( xx / 2 ) ); 
        y = abs( y - ( xx / 2 ) );



    if( ( x + y ) <= ( xx / 2 ) )

        cout << '*';
    else
        cout << ' ';
    } 
cout << endl;
} 
return 0;
```

}

Comment: UB. UB. UB. UB. means Undefined Behavior. `x` and `y` are uninitialized and you're *reading* them.

Comment: `for(float y; y < xx; y++)` what is the initial y here?

Comment: Using `float` type variables for loop index is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number greater than equal to `2` your expression `x = abs( x - ( xx / 2 ) );` results in `x` to decrement. So infinite loop

For example if `xx == 2`, then `x` remains same for each loop as you are decrementing `x` value by `1` in expression `x = abs( x - 1);` and incremented inside for loop

Also please intialize variables inside for loop

EDIT: New Design

```
int temp1, temp2;
for(float y=0; y < xx; y++)
{
    for(float x=0; x < xx; x++)
    {
       temp1 = abs( x - ( xx / 2 ) ); 
       temp2 = abs( y - ( xx / 2 ) );



    //if( ( abs( x - ( xx / 2 ) ) + abs( y - ( xx / 2 ) ) ) <= ( xx / 2 ) )

    if( ( temp1 + temp2 ) <= ( xx / 2 ) )
        cout << '*';
    else
        cout << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks heaps :) so pretty much its an infinite loop because x and y are decrementing in that xpressing x = abs( x - ( xx / 2 ) );
Is there another way too express that so x and y increments

Comment: I think you can solve it by without assigning values to x and y. check my code

Comment: thankyou very much it proceeded too work now. was it not working because i was using the same value that initialized within the for loop, and using temp as a single variable too store the abs of x and y unaffected by the for loops, so it got the correct value?

Comment: yes. you got it. Remeber to intialise loop variable. i modified my code

Answer (score 4):

First, there is undefined behavior. `x` and `y` need to be initialized.

Second, your `x` and `y` never get to be greater than `xx` (if `xx>=2`) since  you have:

```
x = abs( x - ( xx / 2 ) ); 
y = abs( y - ( xx / 2 ) );
```

Hence the infinite loop.

Comment: If `xx = 1` they won't be growing anyway.

Comment: See the info in parentheses: if xx>=2

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your initial `for` loops values there. Assuming you want them to be `0`:

```
for(float y = 0; [...]
{
    for(float x = 0; [...]
    {
```

Otherwise the value used in `y` and `x` is random and depends on what the memory contained before their declaration.

Also the expressions:

```
    x = abs( x - ( xx / 2 ) ); 
    y = abs( y - ( xx / 2 ) );
```

with `xx` constant from input will keep decrementing both x and y (unless `xx` is negative or = 0, which happens when `xx` is less than `2`) therefore leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: -1: Undefined behavior is correct. but the infinite loop condition is not solved by just correcting it. See my answer.

Comment: That's not a fix, that was the actual answer here. Anyways, you're welcome.

Comment: thankyou so much, ill re-comment again if i have any problems :) i just started learning c++ so its kinda new too me

Comment: if xx = 8. doesn't that mean that x and y within the for loop will increment till it gets too 7 which is less than 8. 
so then x = abs(7 - (8/2)) which = 3?
which is the same for y.
so then if((3+3) <= (8/2) 
cout '*'.